# What does CoroutineContext do?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I created Custom Continuation like this

```
class LogContinuation<T>(
    private val cont: Continuation<T>
) : Continuation<T> {
    override val context: CoroutineContext
        get() = cont.context
    override fun resumeWith(result: Result<T>) {
        println("Log: LogContinuation resume with thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        cont.resumeWith(result)
    }
}
```

And custom interceptor

```
val myInterceptor = object: ContinuationInterceptor{
    override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<*>
        get() = ContinuationInterceptor.Key

    override fun <T> interceptContinuation(continuation: Continuation<T>): Continuation<T> {
        println("3 interceptContinuation: ${continuation.context[CoroutineName].toString()}")
        return LogContinuation(continuation)
    }

    override fun releaseInterceptedContinuation(continuation: Continuation<*>) {
        println("4 releaseInterceptedContinuation: ${continuation.context[CoroutineName].toString()}")
    }
}

val myInterceptor2 = object: ContinuationInterceptor{
    override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<*>
        get() = ContinuationInterceptor.Key

    override fun <T> interceptContinuation(continuation: Continuation<T>): Continuation<T> {
        println("5 interceptContinuation: ${continuation.context[CoroutineName].toString()}")
        return Log2Continuation(continuation)
    }

    override fun releaseInterceptedContinuation(continuation: Continuation<*>) {
        println("6 releaseInterceptedContinuation: ${continuation.context[CoroutineName].toString()}")
    }
}
```

And I tried this:

```
fun main(){
    runBlocking(context = myInterceptor + CoroutineName("myRunBlocking") + myInterceptor2 + CoroutineName("myRunBlocking2")){
        println("1 runBlocking start: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        delay(1000L)
        println("2 runBlocking end: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        repeat(1){
            println("${7+it} runBlocking start: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            println("${8+it} runBlocking end: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
    }
}
```

And I get

```
5 interceptContinuation: CoroutineName(myRunBlocking2)
Log: LogContinuation resume with thread: main
1 runBlocking start: main
Log: LogContinuation resume with thread: kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor
2 runBlocking end: kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor
7 runBlocking start: kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor
8 runBlocking end: kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor
6 releaseInterceptedContinuation: CoroutineName(myRunBlocking2)
```

What's happening here? I thought scope can pass only CoroutineContext but, CoroutineIntercepter and CoroutineName can be passed. Those are different types but how can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

`CoroutineContext` is basically a map of `CoroutineContext.Element` items. To make the API a little smoother, coroutines authors introduced a smart trick. Each `Element` is itself a `CoroutineContext` of this single item.

You can verify that both `CoroutineName` and `ContinuationInterceptor` are actually subtypes of `CoroutineContext`.

As an example, let's get your code:

```kotlin
myInterceptor + CoroutineName("myRunBlocking") + myInterceptor2 + CoroutineName("myRunBlocking2")
```

This could be understood as:

```kotlin
// not a true Kotlin code
coroutineContextOf(myInterceptor) +
  coroutineContextOf(CoroutineName("myRunBlocking")) +
  coroutineContextOf(myInterceptor2) +
  coroutineContextOf(CoroutineName("myRunBlocking2"))
```

Here you have 4 different coroutine contexts and you merge them by overwriting the same items with newer ones. As a result, you pass to `runBlocking()` something like:

```kotlin
// not a true Kotlin code
coroutineContextOf(myInterceptor2, CoroutineName("myRunBlocking2"))
```

Comment: What about `CoroutineDispatcher`?? Can you list the Elements? And I don't know why + ignores first interceptor and the first CoroutineName. But the last Interceptor and the last CoroutineName. Should it pass Only one type of Element each?

Comment: Just like with a Map, the last element you add is the only one that will be part of the resulting context. Adding an element creates a new CoroutineContext with the new element type added and replacing any existing element of the same type from the old CoroutineContext.

Comment: Then, the last Context is `CoroutineName("myRunBlocking2")`. But why myInterceptor2 is passed too? @Tenfour04

Comment: `myInterceptor2` is the last one you added, so it is the only interceptor in the final resolved CoroutineContext. Your first interceptor is unused as you can see in the log.

Comment: @c-an This is really the same as for any other map, e.g.: `mapOf("foo" to 1, "bar" to 2) + mapOf("foo" to 3, "bar" to 4)` - the resulting map will have only `3` and `4` as `1` and `2` were replaced. In `CoroutineContext` we can only have a single item of each type. Of course, you can create a composing `ContinuationInterceptor` which will hold a list of interceptors and delegate to them. Anyway, what is your expected behavior for setting multiple coroutine names? What would be the name of a coroutine?

Comment: Thank you I think I got it. @broot But I need to dig into it more to clarify.